# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.pushbots.push.utils.PBPrefs.setCustomHandler(java.lang.String)' on a null object r

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, pushbots

I am use push bots API for push notification i got exception null pointer when i try to implement Custom handler for notifications.

Here is documentation where i learn 
https://pushbots.com/developer/docs/android-sdk-integration

My Android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.assorttech.assorttech" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <permission android:name="com.assorttech.assorttech.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.assorttech.assorttech.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive dataf message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.assorttech.assorttech.MESSAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.thefinestartist.finestwebview.FinestWebViewActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:theme="@style/FinestWebViewTheme.Light"
            >

        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.pushbots.google.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.assorttech.assorttech" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.pushbots.push.DefaultPushHandler" />
        <!--<receiver android:name="com.assorttech.assorttech.customHandler" />-->
        <service android:name="com.pushbots.push.GCMIntentService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

```
public class customHandler extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private static final String TAG = "customHandler";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d(TAG, "action=" + action);
        // Handle Push Message when opened
        if (action.equals(PBConstants.EVENT_MSG_OPEN)) {
            //Check for Pushbots Instance
            Pushbots pushInstance = Pushbots.sharedInstance();
            if(!pushInstance.isInitialized()){
               // Log.d("Initializing Pushbots.");
                Pushbots.sharedInstance().init(context.getApplicationContext());
            }

            //Clear Notification array
            if(PBNotificationIntent.notificationsArray != null){
                PBNotificationIntent.notificationsArray = null;
            }

            HashMap<?, ?> PushdataOpen = (HashMap<?, ?>) intent.getExtras().get(PBConstants.EVENT_MSG_OPEN);
            Log.w(TAG, "User clicked notification with Message: " + PushdataOpen.get("message"));

            //Report Opened Push Notification to Pushbots
            if(Pushbots.sharedInstance().isAnalyticsEnabled()){
                Pushbots.sharedInstance().reportPushOpened( (String) PushdataOpen.get("PUSHANALYTICS"));
            }

            //Start lanuch Activity
            String packageName = context.getPackageName();
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName));
            resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

            resultIntent.putExtras(intent.getBundleExtra("pushData"));
            Pushbots.sharedInstance().startActivity(resultIntent);

            // Handle Push Message when received
        }else if(action.equals(PBConstants.EVENT_MSG_RECEIVE)){
            HashMap<?, ?> PushdataOpen = (HashMap<?, ?>) intent.getExtras().get(PBConstants.EVENT_MSG_RECEIVE);
            Log.w(TAG, "User Received notification with Message: " + PushdataOpen.get("message"));
        }
    }
}
```

Main Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Pushbots.sharedInstance().setCustomHandler(customHandler.class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
Pushbots.sharedInstance().init(this);
```

in your activity's `onCreate()` method.